# Why is asymmetry in percentage change a problem when analyzing time series?

Tags: logarithms, economics, time-series

When analyzing time series, a benefit of log difference, $log(y_t) - log(y_{t-12})$, is that it is symmetric, unlike percentage change, $\frac{y_t-y_{t-12}}{y_{t-12}}$.

My question is —— why is asymmetry an issue? Or how is log difference helpful in ways that percentage change is not when analyzing a time series (more specifically, time series of economic indicators and stock index)?

To start, I looked into this paper but remained confused. https://www.jstor.org/stable/2683905?seq=1

"Avoiding mistakes" is not satisfying as a reason, and why is having an "additive identity" significant?

Thank you!

Comment: [Here's what I see.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vxx9l.jpg) Please use MathJax

Comment: Edited. Thanks for letting me know! The issue somehow didn't show up in the preview.

Comment: Not sure what you are asking.  Within reason you can use any measure of relative change you like.  Given the initial level, and the time series of relative changes (however measured) you should be able to recompute the time series of levels, so no information is lost.  Personally, I dislike percentage because of FX conversions.  Saying EUR declined by $5\%$ against USD is just confusing.  Again, though, it's a simple matter to declare uniform conventions in whatever system you are using.  Clarity and consistency are much more important than the exact metric you select.

Answer (score 1):

Let $y_t$ the $t^{\textrm{th}}$ value of the time series. Suppose that $\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_{t}}=c$. Then the relative change is $\frac{y_{t+1}-y_{t}}{y_{t}}=c-1$. Now suppose that $y_t$ is larger than $y_{t+1}$, with  $\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_{t}}=\frac1{c}$. Here the time series is decreasing. In this case the relative change of is $\frac1{c}-1$, which is not the negative value of $c-1$.

We keep the assumtion that $\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_{t}}=c$. Then the change in terms of logs is $$\ln\left(\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_{t}}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{c}{1}\right)=\ln{(c)}-\ln{(1)}=\ln(c)$$.

In the case of an decreasing series we have the relation $\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_{t}}=\frac1{c}$. And the  change in terms of logs becomes

$$\ln\left(\frac{y_{t+1}}{y_{t}}\right)=\ln\left(\frac{1}{c}\right)=\ln{(1)}-\ln{(c)}=-\ln(c)$$

In the case of logaritmiszed values the changes are symmetric in the sense, that the decreasing change rate is equal to the negative value of the increasing change rate.

Answer (score 1):

A while back, I (hypothetically) bought into a highly volatile mutual fund.  Last year, its price went up by a whopping 300%.  But this year, it went down 75%.

The percentage change framing makes it seem at first glance that I came out ahead 225%, and got a 112.5% annual rate of return.  Awesome!

But in reality, $(1 + 3.00)(1 - 0.75) = 4 \times \frac{1}{4} = 1$, and I'd end up with the same balance I started with.

Now, consider this alternate phrasing of the same numbers: Last year, the price increased (logarithmically) by 2 doubles, but this year, it decreased by 2 doubles.  With this logarithmic framing, it's immediately obvious that the decrease cancels out the increase.

It's not as big of a deal for smaller changes.  For example, a 5% increase followed by a 5% decrease is only a net 0.25% decrease.  But for large changes, the error in naive arithmetic manipulation of percentages gets much larger, as in my first example.